# How to transitive aar dependencies maven to app

Tags: android, maven, gradle, aar

the question as the picture,  app can't invoke the method of library.
 [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use `compile project(":library1")` to include the library into the app

Comment: i hope build  a  aar  for sdk,

Answer (score -1):

already resoved,  the method  is  upload project to maven center  and  use it add transitive =true , example for  (`enter code here`
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }`enter code here`
)